# Add annotation or text to individual box plots when using geom_boxplot, facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `ggplot2` and have constructed a boxplot like so:

[image: fruit ggplot]

This was constructed using the following data and code:

```
structure(list(group = c("C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "V", "V", "V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), fruit = c("apple", 
"apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", 
"apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", 
"apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", 
"apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", 
"apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", 
"apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", 
"apple", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", 
"orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", 
"orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", 
"orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", 
"orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", 
"orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", 
"orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "pear", "pear", "pear", 
"pear", "pear", "pear", "pear", "pear", "pear", "pear", "pear", 
"pear", "pear", "pear", "pear", "pear", "pear", "pear", "pear", 
"pear", "pear", "pear", "pear", "pear", "pear", "pear", "pear", 
"pear", "pear", "pear", "pear", "pear", "pear", "pear"), treatment =  c("pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "post", "post", "post", "post", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post"), subgroup = c(66, 
66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 
67, 67, 67, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 69, 69, 69, 69, 
69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 
71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 73, 
73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 
74, 74, 74, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 77, 77, 77, 
77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 
79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79), conc = c(0.074, 0.204, 
0.118, 0.25, 0.159, 0.283, 0.253, 0.436, 0.295, 0.335, 0.204, 
0.424, 0.254, 0.217, 0.281, 0.153, 0.309, 0.184, 0.341, 0.168, 
0.14, 0.213, 0.29, 0.266, 0.522, 0.219, 0.34, 0.317, 0.053, 0.196, 
0.072, 0.185, 0.269, 0.157, 0.344, 0.398, 0.304, 0.173, 0.212, 
0.197, 0.154, 0.289, 0.212, 0.217, 0.314, 0.337, 0.116, 0.209, 
0.256, 0.165, 0.216, 0.284, 0.148, 0.151, 0.105, 0.097, 0.201, 
0.125, 0.208, 0.334, 0.209, 0.269, 0.388, 0.182, 0.12, 0.28, 
0.253, 0.226, 0.257, 0.193, 0.314, 0.262, 0.12, 0.415, 0.2, 0.209, 
0.202, 0.08, 0.341, 0.221, 0.598, 0.327, 0.258, 0.655, 0.071,  
0.209, 0.234, 0.19, 0.117, -0.01, 0.074, 0.038, 0.06, 0.088, 
0.034, 0.057, 0.099, 0.046, 0.096, 0.166, 0.045, 0.104, 0.08, 
0.248, 0.031, 0.056, 0.101, 0.077, 0.069, 0.251, 0.585, 0.427, 
0.145, 0.109, 0.125, 0.079, 0.068, 0.064, 0.184, 0.202, 0.263, 
0.302, 0.136)), .Names = c("group", "fruit", "treatment", "subgroup", 
"conc"), row.names = c(NA, -123L), class = "data.frame")

require(ggplot2)
plot<-ggplot(prot, aes(x=group, y=conc, fill=factor(treatment)))+ 
geom_boxplot() + 
scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette)+
theme_bw()+
facet_grid(.~fruit)+    
labs(fill="treatment status", y="Concentration (mg.ml-1) ") +
theme(legend.position="bottom", axis.title.y=element_text(size=12, hjust=0.5, vjust=1, face="bold"), axis.text.y=element_text(size=8), axis.title.x=element_text(size=12, hjust=0.5, vjust=0.5, face="bold"), axis.text.x=element_text(size=8))  +
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-0.01,0.7), breaks=seq(0,0.7,0.1))
```

I would now like to add small letters e.g. a, b, c above some of the boxplots to denote statistical significance. For example, an "a" above the first box in the first facet and a "b" above the second and third box in the second facet. However, i can only seem to get letters repeated in every facet or all letters in a single facet.

Amongst many other things that didn't work at all, I have come quite close with these attempts:

```
plot+ annotate("text", label =c("a", "b", "c"), size = 4, x =c(2,1,2), y = c(0.5, 0.3, 0.4))
```

and:

```
df1<-data.frame(group=c(0.8, 1.2, 1.8, 2.2), conc=c(0.4, 0.4), lab="text", id=factor("apple", levels=c("apple", "orange", "pear")), treatment=factor(2, levels=c("pre", "post")))

plot+ geom_text(data=df1, label=c("a", "b", "a", "d"))
```

I feel I need to specify the facet better somewhere "id=factor("apple".... works if I only want annotation in one facet, but not multiple.

Comment: No, sorry, this is my own data set. I could add an image of maybe a sample of it if that would help?

Comment: No worries, I know that this is your first question here. For the R tag we generally ask that you provide a reproducible example, either using a built-in dataset, creating the data within your code, or sharing the data via `dput`. Maybe you could `dput` the first few rows?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've added my data using dput. It seemed the quickest option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to do this is to create a new dataset that contains the plotting information.  This dataset should contain information for each of your three grouping variables (fruit, group, and treatment in order to get the text placed properly.  It will also include a variable for the labels you want to add for each boxplot, and the y position of where the labels should be placed above each boxplot.

Here is an example of how you might make this dataset.  I'm using a few function from *dplyr* to get the three grouping variables into a dataset in the same order as the plot (ordered by fruit, then group, then treatment).

```
library(dplyr)

prot2 = distinct(prot, fruit, group, treatment) %>%
    arrange(fruit, group, treatment)
```

Now add in the y location.  You might want a different placement for each box but here I'm using the max of `conc` from the original dataset plus a little bit more.

```
prot2$yloc = max(prot$conc) + .05
```

Now the labels.  This would be easiest if you had additional information stored somewhere to tell you which labels go on which boxplots.  Here I've written it out by hand to add an "a" for the first box in the first panel and a "b" for the middle two boxes in the second panel, being careful to match the order of `prot2`.  I've included the NA for everything else so I can use `position_dodge` in `geom_text`.

```
prot2$label = c("a", NA, NA, NA, NA, "b", "b", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
```

Now add the text to the plot via `geom_text`, using `position_dodge` to get things lined up appropriately.  I had to change the y limits so the labels would show, which you could do earlier in `scale_y_continuous`.

```
plot + 
    ylim(NA, max(prot$conc) + .05) +
    geom_text(data = prot2, aes(y = yloc, label = label), 
               position = position_dodge(width = .75))
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Thank you soo much aosmith. This was explained soo well and exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding annotations using the same method. Imported the data from excel and used the following code

```
view(pans) 
head(pans) 
rep <- factor(pans$rep) 
trt <- factor(pans$trt) 
yr <- factor(pans$yr) 
st <- factor(pans$st) 
p <- ggplot(pans, aes(x = st, y = act)) 
q<-p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = trt), position = position_dodge(0.8)) + 
       stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", shape=5, size=1.5,
       aes(group = trt), position = position_dodge(0.8)) + 
       scale_fill_manual(name="System", values = c("grey50","grey90", "grey100")) +    
       facet_grid(. ~ yr)+
       theme_bw() 
plot<-q + scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("b","h"), labels=c("BS", "AH")) 
plot2<-plot + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) 
plot2
```

I got the following plot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtGrY.png)

#For adding letters for comparison I used

```
pans2 = distinct(pans, yr, st, trt) %>%
  arrange(yr, st, trt)
pans2$yloc = max(pans$act) + .05
prot2$label = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b")
plot2 + geom_text(data = pans2, aes(y = yloc, label = label), 
          position = position_dodge(width = .75))
```

However, I got the following error

Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.
Error: Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): label = label.
Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add after_stat()?
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.